# Dodecagon inscribed in a circle

Tags: triangles, circles

A regular dodecagon ABCDEFGHIJKL is drawn in a circle radius 2 and centre O. Let P be the point where AD cuts the line OB.
(a) Show that triangle ∆APB is similar to ∆OAB.

I have researched online but to no avail.  I have realised that angle AOB is 30 degrees, OBA is 75 degrees and both triangles share the side AB and the angle OBA.  I want to use AAS or SAS similarity but I can't as I can't figure out the missing side or angle.  Could someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:** You are talking about **similar** triangles, so all you need is two angles to be the same. You showed $\angle OAB=\angle OBA=75^\circ$. $\triangle BOC$ is isosceles, so the perpendicular to $BC$ (and therefore to $AD$) is also an  bisector. Then it's easy to calculate the angle $\angle OPD$, which is equal to $\angle APB$. If it is $75^\circ$, then the two traingles in the problem have angles $75^\circ,75^\circ, 30^\circ$, so they are similar.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: One approach is to draw line AC. Letting Q be the point of intersection of AC with OB, can you prove a related statement about $\Delta ABQ$?